# conway game of life - toroidal approach - rim and corners

Tags: c++

Once again while solving Conway's Game Of Life. The planar approach works just fine. It is the toroidal approach that bother me so much. I've been reviewing my code for a couple of hours now, yet I can't find any gliches. I'll post the two functions which calculate the number of neighbours of each element of our array. The array is a struct with two fields: Val (the current value) and Next (the next value, depending on the number of neighbours the element has).
I should also say that every the functions evaluate the elements which lie on the first and 1st row and the 1st and last column, including the edges.
Thank's to everyone who's reviewing this code, I know it's not that simple.

```
void verifica_lin(int i,int j,int n,int m,int &cnt,matrice a[MAX][MAX]){
    if(i==1){
        if(j==1){
            if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[i+1][j+1].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[2][m].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[n][1].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[n][2].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[n][m].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[1][m].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
        }
        else
            if(j==m){
                if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][2].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i+1][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][m-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
            }
            else{
                if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i+1][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i+1][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
            }
    }
    else
        if(i==n){
            if(j==1){
                if(a[1][1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][2].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n-1][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
            }
            else
                if(j==m){
                    if(a[1][m].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[1][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[1][m-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[n-1][m].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[n][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                }
                else{
                    if(a[1][j].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[1][j+1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[1][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j+1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                }
        }
    if(a[i][j].Val==1){
        if(cnt==2||cnt==3)
            a[i][j].Next=1;
        else
            if(cnt==0||cnt>3)
                a[i][j].Next=0;
    }
    else
        if(cnt==3)
            a[i][j].Next=1;
}
void verify_col(int i,int j,int n,int m,int &cnt,matrice a[MAX][MAX]){
    if(j==1){
        if(i==1){
            if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[i+1][j+1].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[2][m].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[n][1].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[n][2].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[n][m].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[1][m].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
            if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                ++cnt;
        }
        else
            if(i==n){
                if(a[1][1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][2].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n-1][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
            }
            else{
                if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i+1][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i+1][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i-1][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j+1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
            }
    }
    else
        if(j==m){
            if(i==1){
                if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][2].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i+1][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][m].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[n][m-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
                if(a[1][1].Val==1)
                    ++cnt;
            }
            else
                if(i==n){
                    if(a[1][m].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[1][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[1][m-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[n-1][m].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[n][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                }
                else{
                    if(a[i+1][j].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i+1][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i+1][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i-1][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i][j-1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                    if(a[i][1].Val==1)
                        ++cnt;
                }
        }
    if(a[i][j].Val==1){
        if(cnt==2||cnt==3)
            a[i][j].Next=1;
        else
            if(cnt==0||cnt>3)
                a[i][j].Next=0;
    }
    else
        if(cnt==3)
            a[i][j].Next=1;
}
```

Comment: Remove the C tag, this is not valid C code

Comment: Also please pinpoint your issue using a debugger, as this is way too much code. (Not to mention that you did not specify what the problem is, do you have a compiler error, a runtime crash, a wrong result, ...)

Comment: Just nitpicking: it's _matrix_ in singular and _matrices_ in plural, so _matrice_ is incorrect.

Comment: @ForceBru ... in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toroidal approach is similar to the planar approach but allowing the array indices to wrap, so that a "glider" will go off one edge and appear the other side. You must calculate the desired array index first, and make a modulus calculation which will work for a negative index too. For example

```
index = i - 1;
index = (index + DIMENSION) % DIMENSION;
```

EDIT: you say "I know it's not that simple" but only because you make it difficult. You do not need all those different sets of conditions, all 8 neighbours can be done the same way, very simply, for example this line

```
if(a[i+1][j-1].Val == 1)
```

I would make that

```
if( a[(i + 1) % YDIM] [(j - 1 + XDIM) % XDIM].Val == 1 )
```

and so only 8 tests are needed, not the large number of different conditions that you have. Note: you only need to add the `DIMENSION` before taking the modulus, where you have subtracted.

Moving on, your code will be slowed by all those branches. You do not need to test if a cell is `1` before adding `1`. If the cell content is either `0` or `1` all you need to do is add it.

```
cnt += a[(i + 1) % YDIM] [(j - 1 + XDIM) % XDIM].Val;
```